# How do I register the Chart.js Zoom plugin?

Tags: chart.js

I am attempting to use the `chartjs-zoom-plugin` v2.0.1 with Chart.js v4.4.0.  I have the plugin as the file `chartjs-plugin-zoom-2.0.1.min.js`, and I have imported it into my page using

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="chartjs-plugin-zoom-2.0.1.min.js"></script>
```

In order to use the plugin, I must register it.  The [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-zoom/latest/guide/integration.html) contains no information on how to do so.  The only hint is a single example given for the case of something called a "Bundler", which I am not using:

```
Chart.register(zoomPlugin);
```

From what I can tell, the current accepted method of registering Chart.js plugins is via the `plugins` list option to the constructor.  I assume that, as with the Bundler example, the name of the plugin is `zoomPlugin`:

```
let plot1 = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'scatter',
    data: {
        datasets: [{...}]
    },
    plugins: [zoomPlugin],
    options: {...}
}
```

When I try this, it throws the console error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: zoomPlugin is not defined
```

I have also tried the forms

```
Chart.register(zoomPlugin);

let plot1 = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'scatter',
    data: {
        datasets: [{...}]
    },
    options: {...}
}
```

```
let plot1 = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'scatter',
    data: {
        datasets: [{...}]
    },
    options: {...}
}

Chart.register(zoomPlugin);
```

```
let plot1 = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'scatter',
    data: {
        datasets: [{...}]
    },
    options: {...}
}

plot1.register(zoomPlugin);
```

All give the `zoomPlugin is not defined` error.

I give up.  How do I register the `chartjs-zoom-plugin` in Chart.js 4.4.0?

**Edit:** Attempts to import the module

Based on suggestions in the comments to this question, I've tried explicitly importing `chartjs-zoom-plugin` as a module.

The bulk of my JavaScript code is within the typical

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // code that uses Chart.js here ...
</script>
```

tags.  Following [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import), I've tried the following imports:

1)

```
<script type="module">
    import zoomPlugin from './chartjs-plugin-zoom.min.js';
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // code that uses Chart.js here ...
</script>
```

This produces the console error `Uncaught SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: default`.

2)
With curly brackets `{}` around the presumed module name:

```
<script type="module">
    import { zoomPlugin } from './chartjs-plugin-zoom.min.js';
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // code that uses Chart.js here ...
</script>
```

(with and without an extra space inside the brackets).  This produces the console error `Uncaught SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: zoomPlugin`.

3)
Following MDN's suggestion of the [`import()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    import(zoomPlugin);
    // code that uses Chart.js here ...
</script>
```

This produces the console error `Uncaught ReferenceError: zoomPlugin is not defined`.

4. Inside a `type="module"` tag:

```
<script type="module">
    import { zoomPlugin } from './chartjs-plugin-zoom.min.js';
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // code that uses Chart.js here ...
</script>
```

This also produces the console error `Uncaught ReferenceError: zoomPlugin is not defined`.

Comment: It may sound stupid, but have you tried just using the plugin without registering it ?
Ex : https://codepen.io/Frixionder/pen/eYbomxK

P.S. : For the zoom plugin to work, you have to ass Hammer.js as well

Comment: It's not stupid, I did also try the plugin without registering it.  There was no console error (because it was never called), but there was also no zoom functionality.  I did not know about `hammer.js`, I'll give that a try tomorrow.

Comment: *zoomPlugin is not defined*. Have you added this line: `import zoomPlugin from 'chartjs-plugin-zoom';` before register?

Comment: If you include the plugin through the script tag, as described in the [docs](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-zoom/2.0.1/chartjs-plugin-zoom.min.js), (after the chart script and the hammer one) you don't have to register the plugin, nor to declare it in the `plugins` array of your configuration object. The zoom functionality is there in any new chart, as @Frixionder's example clearly shows. `hammer.js` enables touch events - pinch zooming; you should include the script as recommended, but you typically don't use its API directly, the plugin does.

Comment: @YongShun  The last time I checked, JavaScript had no ability to import modules.  I guess that's changed.  I attempted what you suggest and have added the (unsuccessful) results as an edit to the question.